# Cambio de formato de fecha (12 horas) a formato de fecha de elasticsearch(24 horas) con Python

Tags: python, timestamp, elasticsearch

ando trabajando en un agente en `python` para enviar datos a `elasticsearch` y tengo un campo que me lleva una fecha, y necesito que no me lo lea como `string` sino como tiempo,

este es un ejemplo de la fecha que estoy obteniendo `1/29/2019 3:59:06 PM` la fecha que debería obtener debería tener el siguiente formato `2019-01-29T03:59:06.142163-0500`

obtengo la fecha al ejecutar un exe, que me trae información sobre sesiones de RDP, es un campo que pertenece a la session

intente con el siguiente codigo, pero neceisto que sea compatible con 2003 server y timespec no es compatible con python 3.4

```
result = datetime.strptime(cntime, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')   #cntime es el output del campo que ncesito cambiarle el formato
print(result, type(result))
new_time = result.isoformat(timespec='microseconds')
print(new_time, type(new_time))
```

Muchas gracias a todos :)

Comment: Hallip, la idea es que presentes un ejemplo mínimo y verificable de lo que llevas hecho hasta el momento. Las preguntas que incluyen lo anterior, por lo general son ignoradas o terminan cerradas. Esta fecha de ejemplo "1/29/2019 3:59:06 PM", ¿De dónde la obtienes? ¿Una función, un cálculo, una consulta?

Comment: ya he realizado las correcciones, gracias, no había puesto ejemplo puesto que no había podido intentar nada antes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ya logre resolverlo `strftime`  en vez de `isoformat`

```
new_time = result.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f-0500")
```

Comment: Que bien. Saludos